# Buttons pressed in correct order

Tags: programming

I’m trying to figure out the best way of doing this, currently using a bunch messy if-statements which kind of work. I have an IR sensor and three buttons that all need to be activated in the right order. Each sensor/button will activate LEDs and sound effects. First, when sensor1 goes HIGH, button1 can be pressed momentarily, then button2, then button3. If sensor1 is LOW, then nothing should happen when the buttons are pressed. When sensor1 is HIGH then the buttons should be pressed in the right order to progress through the sequence. When sensor1 goes back to LOW it should reset everything and allow the sequence to be run again when HIGH. Should I look into case switches for this?

Thank you

Jason

Comment: what should happen when buttons are pushed in wrong order?

Comment: If sensor1 is LOW, then nothing should happen when the buttons are pressed. When sensor1 is HIGH then the buttons should be pressed in the right order to progess through the sequence.

Comment: what should happen when the sensor state goes low partway through the button sequence? .... please add the description to your question ... do NOT write a comment

Comment: `Should I look into case switches for this?` ... you can, if you want ... the switch/case  block is equivalent to `if else if else if ...` .... is that really the only question that you want to ask?

Comment: and some pointers to learn to code this. I'm still learning. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic application for a state machine, in which you keep track of where your process currently is in the sequence of events that must take place. The 'state' is just a numeric variable whose value you change whenever a significant event takes place.

You would probably assign 0 - Initial state, waiting for an event (or the first event); 1 - Sensor is high, 2 - button-1 went high, 3 - button-1 went low; ... etc.

It always helps to sketch out your state machine on paper, drawing a circle for each state, and arrows from each state 'x' to whatever the next state should be if an event 'y' happens while in state 'x'. The events are sensors and buttons going HIGH or LOW. In a particular state, no arrow for some event means you want to ignore that event while you are in that state.

Once you have drawn the map you can code the state machine. A common way of coding it is with a `switch`-`case` block, one case per defined state. Inside each `case` block, you test only for those events for which there is an arrow leading from that state to another state.

As you add new conditions, (e.g. "What should happen if the sensor goes low after button-1 has been pressed?"), `switch`-`case` logic will be much easier to modify than if you had used a complex collection of `if`-`then` statements. And you *will* be adding new conditions & removing or fixing wrong ones as you discover ways the device fails or humans do things you didn't anticipate. (Ask me how I know this! :-)

It will be really helpful to be able to go back to your state map to visualize what should (or shouldn't) happen, and what to change (on the map) to make that behavior. From the updated map, it is usually easy to see what code needs to be added, deleted, or fixed in the `switch`-`case` block.

Comment: +1 for the finite state machine. For the details on how to implement this in code, I usually point people to Majenko's [Finite State Machine tutorial](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/finite-state-machine), which I find quite good.